# Android Retrofit 2 upload multiple image to server

Tags: android

I'm new for the Android develop, I'm working on an App just like second hand tread, I have an activity is user can upload there items to the server(the text and image), but the problem is upload text is easy, I used Volley to upload the text to server, but I struggle long time to upload the multiple the images to server. 
I saw the Retrofit 2 really good for multiple file upload but I have A lot problems.

Here is ApiService

```
public interface ApiService {
@Multipart
@POST("xxxxxxxxxx.php")
Call<ServerResponse> uploadFile(
                                @Part("uploadedfile")RequestBody uploadedfile,
                                @Part("itemID")RequestBody itemId,
                                @Part MultipartBody.Part file
);

public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
}
```

Here is serverResponse
    public class ServerResponse {

```
@SerializedName("message")
String message;
@SerializedName("error")
boolean error;

public String getMessage(){
    return message;
}

public boolean isError(){
    return error;
}
}
```

Here is Activity

```
public class upload extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php";
public static final String KEY_Title = "title";
public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String KEY_ISBN = "ISBN";
public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
public static final String KEY_CONTECTNUMBER = "contectNumber";

private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String data;

private EditText et_itemTitle;
private EditText et_ISBN;
private EditText et_itemPrice;
private EditText et_itemDescription;
private EditText et_phone;
private Button b_chooseImage;
private Button bPost;
String id = "4";

private LinearLayout lnrImages;
private ArrayList<String> imagesPathList;
private Bitmap yourbitmap;
private Bitmap resized;
private final int PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

    et_itemTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_itemTitle);
    et_ISBN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_ISBN);
    et_itemPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_itemPrice);
    et_itemDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_itemDescription);
    et_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_phone);
    b_chooseImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_chooseImage);
    bPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPost);

    lnrImages = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrImages);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");

    bPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String itemTitle = imagesPathList.get(0).toString();
            final String ISBN = et_ISBN.getText().toString();
            final String itemPrice = et_itemPrice.getText().toString();
            final String itemDescription = et_itemDescription.getText().toString();
            final String contectNumber = et_phone.getText().toString();

            final String user = ((globalV) getApplication()).getUserID();
            final String session = ((globalV) getApplication()).getSessionID();
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jsonResponse.getBoolean("error");

                        if (error) {
                            String errorMessage = jsonResponse.getString("message");
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(upload.this);
                            builder.setMessage(errorMessage)
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            String successMessage = jsonResponse.getString("message");
                            System.out.println(successMessage+"---------------");
                            String itemID = jsonResponse.getString("itemID");


                            ((globalV) getApplication()).setItemID(itemID);
                            File file = new File(imagesPathList.get(0));
                            System.out.print(imagesPathList.get(0)+"====-=-=-=-=-=---=-=");

                            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                                    .setLenient()
                                    .create();

                            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), file);
                            RequestBody uploadedfile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());
                            RequestBody itemId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());
                            MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploadedfile", file.getName(), requestBody);
                            System.out.print(file+"xxxxxxxxxx");

                            ApiService apiService =ApiService.retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
                            Call<ServerResponse> call = apiService.uploadFile(uploadedfile, itemId, fileToUpload);
                            call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                                    ServerResponse serverResponse = response.body();
                                    if (serverResponse != null) {
                                        if (serverResponse.isError()) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }else {
                                        assert  serverResponse != null;
                                        Log.v("Response", serverResponse.toString());
                                    }
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                                    Log.v("OnFailure", t.toString());
                                }
                            });  //stop

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(upload.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(KEY_Title, itemTitle);
                    map.put(KEY_ISBN, ISBN);
                    map.put(KEY_PRICE, itemPrice);
                    map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, itemDescription);
                    map.put(KEY_CONTECTNUMBER, contectNumber);
                    map.put("userID", user);
                    map.put("sessionID", session);
                    map.put("id", id);
                    return map;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(upload.this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        }

    });
    b_chooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(upload.this, CustomPhotoGalleryActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
            if (imagesPathList != null) {
                Toast.makeText(upload.this, " no images are selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE) {
            imagesPathList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] imagesPath = data.getStringExtra("data").split("\\|");
            try {
                lnrImages.removeAllViews();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < imagesPath.length; i++) {
                imagesPathList.add(imagesPath[i]);
                yourbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagesPath[i]);
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(yourbitmap);
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                lnrImages.addView(imageView);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And I have other activity to select images

```
public class CustomPhotoGalleryActivity extends Activity {
private GridView grdImages;
private Button btnSelect;

private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
private String[] arrPath;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private int ids[];
private int count;
int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_gallery);
    grdImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdImages);
    btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){

        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }

    final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    grdImages.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imagecursor.close();

    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                    cnt++;
                    selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                }
            }
            if (cnt == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select at least one image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("data", selectImages);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                System.out.print("===="+selectImages);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

private void setBitmap(final ImageView iv, final int id) {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            iv.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }.execute();

}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
   private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter(){
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery_item, null);
            holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);
            holder.chkImage = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.chkImage.setId(position);
        holder.imgThumb.setId(position);
        holder.chkImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int id = cb.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        holder.imgThumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = holder.chkImage.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                    holder.chkImage.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    holder.chkImage.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            setBitmap(holder.imgThumb, ids[position]);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        holder.chkImage.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
        holder.id = position;
        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgThumb;
    CheckBox chkImage;
    int id;
}

}
```

Probably I need request the server at the same time, please can someone help me.............

Answer (score 2):

If you want to upload multiple image with single key. Make `MultipartBody.Part` as Array.

```
Call<ServerResponse> uploadFile(
    @Part("uploadedfile")RequestBody uploadedfile,
    @Part("itemID")RequestBody itemId,
    @Part MultipartBody.Part[] file
);


MultipartBody.Part[] imageParts = new MultipartBody.Part[10];

for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    File file = new File(IMAGE_FILE[index]);
    RequestBody surveyBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    imageParts[index] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("SurveyImage", file.getName(), uploadedfile);
}
```

Comment: How can I send a title for each image?